# I need help with chromium

Tags: 12.10, chromium

I am running Ubuntu 12.10 on a eee pc 1001px and it feels pretty sluggish compared to the win7 that I had previously installed even though it is the only OS on the machine right now. I installed chromium and tabs keep crashing with the 'He's dead, Jim' message, which alludes that chromium isn't getting enough memory. I did not have this problem before the Ubuntu install so I am guessing that there is some way to get it to allocate more of the one gig of ram installed so it won't crash as much.

Answer (score 0):

With 1 gig of ram I am surprised that Windows 7 was not more sluggish. It would be nice to see more of your system specs but it sounds to me like you might benefit from a more lightweight distro like [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/)